# How to customize ImageUploader component?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, image-upload, dynamic-rows

I am currently using an ImageUploader in a dynamic rows element. However, I have a couple of obstacles I need to overcome:

1) How to remove the "Upload" button?

2) When using the "Select from Gallery" feature, I can see the image I chose in the preview, but when I enter the product again this data is empty (I can't see the image in the preview square) - is there any mapping I'm missing?

3) How can I remove the upper "Image" label?

In the image below you can find what it looks like now, and highlighted in red are the sections I want to hide/remove.
[image: dynamic-rows component]

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: Hello,
Do you have this image related thing through ui component?

Comment: Hi, what I used was a DataProvider, with componentType and formElement fields as imageUploader, the component 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/image-uploader' and the previewTmpl as 'Magento_Catalog/image-preview'. Do you know how all these pieces tie together? Thank you!